# Many to many relationship with extra information

Tags: mysql, sql, database, design-patterns, database-design

I'm having this Reddit like relationship shown as below. Basic idea is, each user can join many communities, and write many blogs in each community.

And there's community specific information about this user, like reputation etc. My question is, is it a good practice to put the extra information on the associative table (i.e. UserCommunities)? Why any why not?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: why does your Blogs table has communities_id and UserCommunities_Communities_id ? Won't the value be same ?

Comment: I've done this several times, with no regrets.  What d you think you would gain by putting reputation in a separate table?

Comment: @WalterMitty Nothing really... I'm pretty new to DB design thus I was a bit worried about potential drawbacks that I didn't consider of

Comment: @k1133 apologies. Blogs should really only contain communityId, userCommunityId

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic forces considered for relational database designs :

1. Reduce redundancy and dependency of data. (Normalization)
2. The query pattern of the application. (Use case/Scenarios)

The Normalization part is well documented. You can refer wiki or [this](http://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) for details on that. 
You should definitely consider this if your concern is over the data growth or if you observe that changing one field value requires you to change multiple column values(data dependency).

The second part is more subjective to your requirement.
If your query pattern requires some data across queries and it is not very costly(space wise) to keep both data in same table, one can ignore/bend the normalization technique.

For your example:

If user table had data specific to user like their initials , address , preferences , then you can have it as separate table.

similarly for User Communities table , if apart from reputation it has data like number of posts, number of likes etc etc. It can/should be a different table

> why not?

You can refer the normalization forms for the benefits. :)

But if your use case/query pattern  is that "given a user and blog, tell me user's reputation" or something similar and there is no extra data, you can keep the reputation in the same table.

> Why

It will simplify your queries . Instead of join across tables it will be straight forward query with less complexity.